# JmsTemplate - broker name issue (ObjectName)

Tags: spring, jms, activemq-classic, jmx, jmstemplate

We are using on our junit tests some activemq manipulations (via jmx).

we have 2 main environments:

1) local

2) QA

as part of our code for the JMS manipulation we use the activemq objectName.

Problem is - in one environment the

```
 Objectname = 'org.apache.activemq:type=Broker,brokerName=localhost'
```

And on the other environment  :

```
Objectname = 'org.apache.activemq:BrokerName=localhost,Type=Broker'
```

Our code unfortunately uses the hard coded name of the object name like so:

```
...

String operationName = "removeQueue";
                                  String parameter = q.getName();
                                  ObjectName activeMQ = new ObjectName(
                                                   "org.apache.activemq:type=Broker,brokerName=localhost");
                                  if (parameter != null) {
                                  Object[] params = { parameter };
                                  String[] sig = { "java.lang.String" };
                                  conn.invoke(
                                          activeMQ,
                                          operationName,
                                          params,
                                          sig);
                                  }
                                  else {
                                  conn.invoke(
                                          activeMQ,
                                          operationName,
                                          null,
                                          null);
                                  }
                              }
                              catch (Exception e) {
                                  throw new RuntimeException(
                                             e);
                              }
```

This ofcourse works on one env but not on the other, 
Is  there a way to set the Objectname? or get the Object name before connecting to the JMS (we are using JmsTemplate)

Thanks

Comment: What about setting it as system property or in some environment-specific configuration file?

Comment: Is it the same AMQ version or different? Also what versions do you actually use?